# MySQL GROUP_CONCAT on 3 way join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

**authors**

```
author_id    last_name    first_name    organization
1            Smith        John          Org A
2            Smith        Mary          Org A 
3            Doe          John          Org B   
4            Doe          Jane          Org C
5            Jones        John          Org C
6            Sarduchi     Guido         Org A
```

**author__papers**

```
author_id    paper_id    is_conctact_author
1            1001        0
2            1001        0
3            1001        0 
4            1002        0
5            1002        0
6            1001        1
```

**org_info (this is already filtered on is_contact_author < 1)**

```
paper_id    organization   idx    org_count 
1001        Org A          1      2
1001        Org B          2      2    
1002        Org C          1      1
```

What I need is a result set that looks like this based on the sample data above:

```
paper_id    organization    last_names      idx    org_count
1001        org A           Smith, Smith    1      2
1001        org B           Doe             2      2
1002        Org C           Doe, Jones      1      1
```

I get close with:

```
select AP.paper_id as paper_id, organization
  GROUP_CONCAT(last_name SEPARATOR ', '), idx, org_count
from authors A
inner join authors__papers AP ON A.author_id = AP.author_id
inner join org_info O ON O.paper_id = AP.paper_id AND O.organization = A.organization
where AP.is_contact_author < 1
group by O.organization, AP.paper_id
order by paper_id;
```

...but the last names are duplicated. If I add a DISTINCT to the GROUP_CONCAT, I loose the values where the last name is the same (e.g. Smith) even though it's a different person.

Any thought on how best to take this sample data and get the desired output without the issues?

TIA!

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says:
If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Comment: The columns in the group by ARE in the select

Comment: Yes, but there are columns (idx, org_count) in the select but not in the group by. (Invalid in newer MySQL versions, unpredictable result in older versions.)

Comment: can you add an example in which you have an unwanted duplicate last_name? Because in your example I don't see a case in which the same author appears two times in the same article, so you should not worry about this issue. Or maybe I'm missin something

Comment: If you run the query I posted you should see duplicates in the GROUP_CONCAT on the last_name field output.similar to Smith, Smith, Smith, Smith, Smith, Smith instead of Smith, Smith. If DISTINCT is added to the GROUP_CONCAT then just one Smith is output and 2 are needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding your question correctly, one option would be to move your query to a subquery, add the `authorid` field with `distinct`, and then apply the `group_concat` to the outer query.  Something like this:

```
select paper_id, organization, GROUP_CONCAT(last_name SEPARATOR ', '), 
       idx, org_count
from (
    select distinct AP.paper_id as paper_id, organization, a.last_name, a.author_id, 
           idx, org_count
    from authors A
      inner join authors__papers AP ON A.author_id = AP.author_id
      inner join org_info O ON O.paper_id = AP.paper_id AND O.organization = A.organization
    where AP.is_contact_author < 1
) t
group by organization, paper_id
order by paper_id;
```

This way you could still return 2 Smiths for example, but they would have different author ids.

Comment: I still get the duplicates and now the idx values are skewed as well.

Comment: @DDurham -- Having trouble with sql fiddle or would show you an example, but this is working for me...  Start with running the inner query and see if it doesn't return the correct results (prior to the group_concat).  If so, this should work.  if not, please elaborate further.

Comment: Thanks, playing with it now and will let you know. I was also going to post a fiddle but was running into issues there as well.

Comment: @DDurham -- fiddle seems to be back up: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/503031/2 -- looks the same as your desired results.

Comment: The dups and idx skewing was coming form org_info which is a temp table that was not being dropped between runs. Fixed that and the subquery options works great! Thanks!